# Missing In-App-Purchase section in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app in prepare for submission state.
I also have in app purchase items for this app.
Last week I linked them to my app and submitted it for review.
During the weekend a developer rejected it.
Now I'd like to resubmit the fixed build but the IAP section is completely missing.
How do I make it visible again?

Comment: Where exactly are you looking for your in app purchase(s)? Go to "My Apps" section and select "Features". There you'll find all your IAPs.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am facing the same issue now. can you reply how to resolve it ?

Comment: same thing happened to me, after got rejected because i was missing restore purchase button, i changed status from Rejected to "Prepare for submission" to the same version i was working before, the InApp section was missing. It seems the in-app purchase selection appears once on the first status when the a specific version is created, if it reverts to that same status it doesn't appear anymore and the selection remains the same. If you don't feel safe, create a new version and select your desired in-app feature.

Comment: This is really confusing. I also did developer reject to re-upload the binary. And I don't see the section to link IAPs when submitting. I do see in the IAPs that they are "Waiting for Review". So my assumption is that App Store Review will review it as part of the approval.

Comment: Update: after app store approval (of a build that I developer rejected and then re-submitted for review), my IAPs went from "Waiting for Review" to "Approved". So it seems like they are in the approval queue, even though you can no longer link/add them from the App Store new version submission page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue. This is on the form where you enter the details for a specific version. The first time you submit a new version there's an "In-App Purchases" section which lets you link specific IAPs to that version. Then, if it's rejected, this section of the form disappears. So what's missing is the ability to link specific products to specific versions.

For clarity, the top tab selected is "App Store" and then in the left-hand menu under the IOS App section you select the version of the app you are working on.

Comment: That is correct! You can safely submit the app and the in-app purchase will be there.

Comment: What tripped me up: the "In App Purchases" section is missing completely if you don't have any IAPs in the "Ready to Submit" state; and the state doesn't become "Ready to Submit" until you add "the screenshot for review purposes."

Comment: Every step of developing for Apple is designed for maximum pain. Death by a thousand cuts every single time.

Answer (score 7):

In-app purchases section in "App Store" tab visible only if you have atleast one in-app purchase with status "Ready to submit".

You will **NOT** see In-app purchases section in "App Store" tab while single/all purchase item/s in "Waiting for Review" status. They should be "Ready to Submit".

Simply do **NOT** press "Submit for Review" button from "Features" tab.

Just attach your purchase item/s from "App Store" tab and submit binary.

Comment: My In-App Purchases have the state "Waiting for Review" (Without an app in review) for a while now, how do I get them to be "Ready to Submit"?

Comment: @Jonas . delete that inapp item and create another one. Thank apple for that.

Comment: @Duck Can we delete the in-app item and add it again with the same product id?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the answer from one of the comments above

> What tripped me up: the "In App Purchases" section is missing completely if you don't have any IAPs in the "Ready to Submit" state; and the state doesn't become "Ready to Submit" until you add "the screenshot for review purposes." – Brett Apr 2 '17 at 20:17

In addition, the "In App Purchases" section only appears before submitting the app for review. One it is "Waiting For Review", the section does not show up. In the ongoing updates of the app, new IAP will be submitted under the tab Features > In-App Purchases.

Comment: though this is unrelated to the question, since if the submit got rejected, the section will not appear even if you add "screenshot for review purposes"