# Linking In-App purchase missing on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

[image]

Last week I successfully created IAP product on "Features=>In-App Purchase" Menu on iTunes Connect. And I tested that product through sandbox and it was worked fine.

And I also can link my IAP product to my specific version of iOS app. (App Store => specific version of iOS APP ) So I submitted app for review.

However, During the state of "In-Review", I found some critical bugs and I rejected submit on myself. (Developer rejected). I fixed bugs, and tried to submit again with new binary.

**But I can't find linking IAP product on my app. Last time I remember there was a section for linking IAP product to my app on specific version of iOS app. Like below, there is no linking section. it was disappeard.**

I totally don't understand... I signed the contracts, and input bank information successfully. I can create IAP products, but I can't link these to my app. What is the problem?

I read some stackoverflow questions, perhaps [Missing In-App-Purchase section in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962649/missing-in-app-purchase-section-in-itunes-connect) this question is very similar with my situation but I can't resolve it. Thanks in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Guys I found solution...

Crazy... your IAP's status in "waiting for review" you can't link that product to your app.

At least you have to have one of "ready-to-submit" IAP product...

WTF